# Does immediately mean immediately as we understand it

Tags: jesus, gospels

When Jesus called His disciples and the word says they left "immediately" Matt 4:22, did they actually drop everything "immediately" as we think in the west, or was there some type of cultural interaction between family and the called ones before they actually left to follow Him?

Comment: Thus question  has also been asked on Christianity ---> https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/61599/does-immediately-mean-immediately

Answer (score 2):

The Greek word is εὐθέως (*eutheōs*).  It is the adverb form of the adjective εὐθύς (*eythys*), which means "straight" or "direct".

εὐθέως seems to always has the meaning of "immediately" or "at once" in both the New Testament and Old (Septuagint).  It appears 88 times in the New Testament and 15 times in the Septuagint.  It conveys the sense of moving from one action to another, without any other intervening action in between.

Comment: So it would seem via your answer that the called men actually left at the moment of HIS calling  without any other considerations of business or family.